# How can I return String inputs from a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, return

In my code, I have the user enter the "number of titles". Then, I prompt the user to enter the title names until it equals the amount of titles there are that the user entered just before. What I want to do is return the title names when I call the method in my main method. But, when I try to return the variable I have that reads the title names, it can not be accessed because it is out of the loop. Here is that method:

```
public static String getTitles(){
    Scanner numberOfTitles = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of titles: ");
    int titlesAmount = numberOfTitles.nextInt();
    int count = 1;
    while (count <= titlesAmount){
        Scanner titlesReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter title: ");
        String titlesInput = titlesReader.next();
        count++;
    }
    return titlesInput;
}
```

I want to return that variable titlesInput because that contains the names the user entered but I don't know how to access it outside of the loop. Would appreciate if someone could show me how to do that.

Comment: A method which returns a String can only return **one** String. You want to return **several** Strings. So the method should return an array of Strings (or a List<String>). Read the tutorial about arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. Also, you need a single Scanner to read everything. No need to create a new Scanner every time you want to read something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a list (or array) of Strings rather than a single String.

I changed your method to do this so you can get the general idea of what I mean. I'm not sure my syntax is 100% correct for Java, but it should get the gist across.

```
public static List<String> getTitles(){
    Scanner numberOfTitles = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of titles: ");
    int titlesAmount = numberOfTitles.nextInt();
    int count = 1;

    List <String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (count <= titlesAmount){
        Scanner titlesReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter title: ");
        String titlesInput = titlesReader.next();
        titles.add(titlesInput);
        count++;
    }
    return titles;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return multiple strings from the method, you have to return a list of strings:

```
public static List<String> getTitles() { ... }
```

Then, inside the method, just add all strings you want to return to a list, and return the list at the end:

```
Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of titles: ");
int titlesAmount = inputReader.nextInt();
int count = 1;
List<String> titles = new ArrayList();

while (count <= titlesAmount){
    System.out.println("Enter title: ");
    titles.add(inputReader.next());
    count++;
}
return titles;
```

Note that I only created one `Scanner` object. You don't need to create multiple `Scanner`s for this task.

But an even better solution would be to have just one global `Scanner` object somewhere outside the method and just use that for all your input needs.

Comment: @VeselinRomic But I beat you by 1 minute ;)

Comment: And fixed the multiple Scanner issue.

Comment: That's what I get for being a slow typer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You must define the variable inside the method scope. Not in while loop scope if you wanna return that.
And it is always better not to use direct String objects and manipulating them inside loops since it will cause more memory. Better to use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` based on your choice

```
public static String getTitles(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of titles: ");
    int titlesAmount = scanner.nextInt();
    int count = 1;
    StringBuilder sbReturn = new StringBuilder();
    while (count <= titlesAmount){
        System.out.println("Enter title: ");
        sbReturn.append(scanner.next()).append(",");
        count++;
    }
    return sbReturn.toString();
}
```

Comment: @Takendarkk oh I forget about that. I corrected that. Thanks for comment and rep :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the variable's scope be on the outermost level, you need to initialize the String outside of the while loop. The compiler can never know for sure if the code inside of a while loop statement will ever execute (even if the condition is true) so it does not leak any variables within a loop's block to the outer block.

In addition to that, there are three things you need to know. First, you only need one Scanner object for reading all of your input. Second, if you want to return a bunch of Strings, in this case, all of your titles, you need a `List<String>` object as your return type. Lastly, whenever you want to iterate x amount of times, a for loop is always more readable than a while loop that uses a counter variable.

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
public static List<String> getTitles() {
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of titles: ");
    int titlesAmount = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < titlesAmount; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter title: ");
        titles.add(sc.next());
    }
    return titles;
}
```